# Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException for behavior method

Tags: yii2

I have set some properties in behavior() method and I'm getting this error

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access'=>[
            'class'=> AccessControl::className(),
            'only'=>['create','update'],
            'rules'=>[
                'allow'=>true,
                'roles'=>['@'],
            ],


        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['POST'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

please someone see it to solve

Answer (score 1):

[`AccessControl::$rules`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol#$rules-detail) should be array of rules, so you need something like this:

```
'access' => [
    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
    'only' => ['create','update'],
    'rules' => [
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change as per below code

```
'access'=>[
            'class'=> AccessControl::className(),
            'rules'=>[
                'actions'=>['create','update'],
                'allow'=>true,
                'roles'=>['@'],
            ],
```